# Ansible roles. Default values

Tags: ansible

I cannot find the answer in the docs, neither I can find an example: is it possible to name files in `role/defaults/` other then `main.yml`? I mean, is `main.yml` the only valid name for a file with default values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the sound of this documentation;

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#roles

> Roles are just automation around ‘include’ directives as described
> above, and really don’t contain much additional magic beyond some
> improvements to search path handling for referenced files. However,
> that can be a big thing!
>
> This designates the following behaviors, for each role ‘x’:
>
> If roles/x/tasks/main.yml exists, tasks listed therein will be added
> to the play
>
> If roles/x/handlers/main.yml exists, handlers listed
> therein will be added to the play
>
> If roles/x/vars/main.yml exists,
> variables listed therein will be added to the play
>
> If
> roles/x/defaults/main.yml exists, variables listed therein will be
> added to the play
>
> If roles/x/meta/main.yml exists, any role
> dependencies listed therein will be added to the list of roles (1.3
> and later) Any copy, script, template or include tasks (in the role)
> can reference files in roles/x/{files,templates,tasks}/ (dir depends
> on task) without having to path them relatively or absolutely

**Q:** I mean, is main.yml the only valid name for a file with default values?
**A:** Sounds like it is only if you are wanting ansible to automatically load certain var_files for that role and auto `include` the task file.

**Q:** Is it possible to name files
**A:** Yes, it just means in the playbook you have to use the `include` directive and explicitly point it to the unique task file name.

Example:

```
- name: Do role
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include: roles/operations/tasks/installProgram.yml
```

Comment: If I name a defaults file `role/defaults/a.yml` and then include it with `include` statement in my task (not sure it's possible) will it be really *default*? Will it be overridable? How does Ansible know that this include must have lower precedence as regular vars?

Comment: Ansible newbie here. Still learning so ain't really sure about the comment, my apology. I think when you use the `include` statement it just means 'hey run that yml script' and it doesn't have all the role magic mentioned in the quote text like the automatic variable loading.

Answer (score 5):

As you tell in the comments, it's possible to call a file anything else under the `roles/my_role/defaults/`. The issue is that files like `roles/my_role/defaults/anything_else.yml` will never be loaded as default. Even you will be able to load it with `include_vars`, it will gain the [high precedence of included vars (18/22)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

Nevertheless, since Ansible 2.6, your are able to use a directory `main` in place of a `main.yml` file!

By doing so, you can reach your goal by splitting your variables into `roles/my_role/defaults/main/something.yml`, `roles/my_role/defaults/main/anything_else.yml`, …

More details in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51818265/4842717).

But indeed this feature is not yet documented (I just created an [issue about that](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/62354)).

Answer (score 2):

Ansible will look in the roles/ directory for tasks, variables, handlers, etc by default. roles/default is simply an example provided in their docs. You can structure your roles differently to suit your needs. For example, I have mine set up as such;

```
roles/windows/<somerole>/tasks/main.yml
roles/linux/<somerole>/tasks/main.yml
```

main.yml is the only file that will be loaded automatically (by "default") when running playbooks. If you want to specify another file name for whatever reason you need to use the include function and point to your file as described above.

The "[Best Practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout)" guide offers some good insight into directory structuring.