# How to split an ansible role's `defaults/main.yml` file into multiple files?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, file-organization

In some ansible roles (e.g. `roles/my-role/`) I've got quite some big default variables files (`defaults/main.yml`). I'd like to split the `main.yml` into several smaller files. Is it possible to do that?

I've tried creating the files `defaults/1.yml` and `defaults/2.yml`, but they aren't loaded by ansible.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The feature I'm describing below has been available since Ansible 2.6, but got a bugfix in v2.6.2 and another (minor) one in v2.7.
To see a solution for older versions, see Paul's answer.

---

#### `defaults/main/`

Instead of creating `defaults/main.yml`, create a *directory* — **`defaults/main/`** — and place all YAML files in there.

- `defaults/main.yml` → **`defaults/main/*.yml`**

Ansible will load any `*.yml` file inside that directory, so you can name your files like `roles/my-role/defaults/main/{1,2}.yml`.

Furthermore, it's even possible to create sub-directories like `roles/my-role/defaults/main/subdir_1/foo.yml`.

Note, the old file — `defaults/main.yml` — must not exist. See [this Github comment](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/36357#issuecomment-463855017).

---

#### `vars/main/`

**By the way**, the above solution also works for `vars/`:

- `vars/main.yml` → **`vars/main/*.yml`**

---

### further details

The feature has been introduced in v2.6 — [git commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/95ce00ff00e2907e89f4106747abaf9d4e4ccd7f), [Pull Request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/36357), [main Github issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14248).

There have been two bugfixes:

- v2.7 fix: [git commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/2e62e3659030d6ce1c9a0a7c43f29631aa4286a9), [Pull Request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/41761) — **backported** to v2.6.2: [commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/a0138e54614ebf2e341163de255e6639ada553ca), [Pull Request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/43095)
- v2.7 fix: [git commit](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/0ff04ad41b55e19af8671b8ea33030b10927771a), [Pull Request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/41067), [bug discussion](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/36357#issuecomment-394186291)

Comment: you're right, I had the wrong file structure, worked after fixing that, removed my comment, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If you aren't using 2.6 (which you probably should, but I understand that isn't always an option), then you might find [include_vars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/include_vars_module.html)     useful.

```
- name: Include vars of stuff.yaml into the 'stuff' variable (2.2).
  include_vars:
    file: stuff.yaml
    name: stuff

- name: Conditionally decide to load in variables into 'plans' when x is 0, otherwise do not. (2.2)
  include_vars:
    file: contingency_plan.yaml
    name: plans
  when: x == 0

- name: Load a variable file based on the OS type, or a default if not found. Using free-form to specify the file.
  include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yaml"
    - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yaml"
    - default.yaml

- name: Bare include (free-form)
  include_vars: myvars.yaml

- name: Include all .json and .jsn files in vars/all and all nested directories (2.3)
  include_vars:
    dir: vars/all
    extensions:
        - json
        - jsn

- name: Include all default extension files in vars/all and all nested directories and save the output in test. (2.2)
  include_vars:
    dir: vars/all
    name: test

- name: Include default extension files in vars/services (2.2)
  include_vars:
    dir: vars/services
    depth: 1

- name: Include only files matching bastion.yaml (2.2)
  include_vars:
    dir: vars
    files_matching: bastion.yaml
```

Note that this is a task directive, though. It isn't as neat as just being able to include it into the defaults file itself.